# Azure blob storage - error displaying uploaded images

Tags: azure, .net-core, blob, azure-blob-storage

I've tried lots of different approaches & read lots of answers on SO but reaching out for help with this as I've hit a wall.

I have a storage account & container on azure, I'm successfully uploading images there but for some reason they seem to be corrupting.

I cannot access any image via an img tag nor can I view them (in windows photos) if I download them directly from the container.

I believe I have the correct configuration, public access level **blob** (I've also tried public access level **container**).

*container access level*
[image: access level img]

*view of the uploaded blob*
[image: azure blob img]

The image doesn't display via the url on my razor page

*html img tag*
[image: missing img razor page]

Nor am I able to view it if I download & open in windows

*downloaded img from container*
[image: corrupt image]

*2 examples of filestream approaches I've tried below*

```
    //approach 1   
     
    
        using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
                    {
                        BlobClient blobClient = container.GetBlobClient(fileName);
                        await blobClient.UploadAsync(fileStream, new BlobHttpHeaders { ContentType = "image/jpg" });
                    }
    
    //approach 2
    
            using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
            {
                container.UploadBlob(attachment.FileName, fileStream);
            }
    
//service
    public async Task<bool> UploadSample(IFormFile attachment)
            {
                var configSection = Configuration.GetSection("AzureBlobStorge");
                var connectionString = configSection.GetSection("ConnectionString").Value;
                var containerName = configSection.GetSection("ContainerName").Value;
    
                string fileName = Path.GetFileName(attachment.FileName);
                string filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot\\images\\profiles", fileName);
    
                BlobContainerClient container = new BlobContainerClient(connectionString, containerName);
    
                container.SetAccessPolicy(PublicAccessType.BlobContainer);
    
                using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
                {
                    container.UploadBlob(attachment.FileName, fileStream);
    
                    //BlobClient blobClient = container.GetBlobClient(fileName);
                    //await blobClient.UploadAsync(fileStream, new BlobHttpHeaders { ContentType = "image/jpg" });
                }
                return true;
            }

//controller
        [HttpPost]
        [ActionName("ProfilePicsAsync")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> ProfilePicsAsync(Members item)
        {
            try
            {
                IFormFile formFile = HttpContext.Request.Form.Files[0];
                var member = await _cosmosDbService.GetItemAsync(formFile.Name); //Id passed in the formfile object under name
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    if (IsAdminUser())
                    {
                        if (formFile != null)
                        {
                            await _blobStorageService.UploadSample(formFile);
                        }
                        return RedirectToAction("Index");
                    }
                    return BadRequest("Not Authorised");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if(ex is BusinessRuleException)
                {
                    return BadRequest(new BusinessRuleException(ex.Message));
                }
            }

//view
<form asp-action="ProfilePicsAsync" asp-controller="Home" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
    <p>INPUT</p>
    <input asp-for="Attachment" Name="@Model.Id" />
    <button type="submit" id="btnUpload" class="btn btn-primary">Upload</button>
</form>
```

Comment: You are uploading it with the wrong content-type.

Comment: I believe the issue is with your upload process. Can you share the code for uploading the image?

Comment: I've updated my post with the upload code, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, the issue is indeed with your upload code. Basically you're uploading a zero byte file. This is happening because of the following line of code:

```
using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
```

When you use `FileMode.Create`, if the file exists it will be overwritten. From the documentation [`here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filemode?view=net-5.0#fields):

> Specifies that the operating system should create a new file. **If the
> file already exists, it will be overwritten**. This requires Write
> permission. FileMode.Create is equivalent to requesting that if the
> file does not exist, use CreateNew; otherwise, use Truncate. If the
> file already exists but is a hidden file, an
> UnauthorizedAccessException exception is thrown.

So essentially you're overwriting the file you want to upload with a zero byte file and then uploading that zero byte file.

To fix this, please change the above line of code to:

```
using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
```

After that both your upload and download should work.

Comment: Thankyou Guarav, that made perfect sense & I got really excited however it hasn't fixed the problem. I'm going to post more of my code in the question in case anything else jumps out as being incorrect. I really appreciate the time you've taken to answer so far.

Comment: What issues are you running into with your updated code?

Comment: Something really weird happened after I made your suggested change actually, it seems to be saving as some kind of audio file, when I opened it up I could hear people talking. Just made the whole thing even more strange! https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-upload-process-images?tabs=dotnet%2Cazure-powershell I'm thinking I might give this tutorial a try & see what the code generated by CLI commands looks like

Comment: So you’re uploading an image file however a different file is getting uploaded. Is that right? Can you compare the local file that you’re uploading with the file that’s getting uploaded? Are both of them same?

Comment: yeah, they appear exactly the same, file extension & everything, I'll see how I go with the tutorial tonight & update if I get a win

Comment: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/storage-blob-upload-from-webapp

The images controller in this tutorial basically had a working solution for me, I threw out most of my code & started again.

Thanks again for helping out :)

Answer (score 0):

**Tutorial**: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-upload-process-images?tabs=dotnet%2Cazure-powershell

**Repo**: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/storage-blob-upload-from-webapp

The images controller in this tutorial basically had a working solution for me, I threw out most of my code & started again.

This was the important bit

```
if (StorageHelper.IsImage(formFile))
{
    if (formFile.Length > 0)
    {
        using (Stream stream = formFile.OpenReadStream())
        {
            isUploaded = await StorageHelper.UploadFileToStorage(stream, formFile.FileName, storageConfig);
        }
    }
}
```